# Changing a number to a string and then adding up the individual integers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, sum

I have tried multiple functions so far but the piece that I am stuck on is how to setup the function so that the argument will be 1) split into an array, 2) added together then 3) returned. I am not sure if I am looking at the question right, but I am assuming to use string.Split. Any help is welcome! Thanks!

1. Write a function that takes a number an an argument and returns the sum of each individual digit. So an input of 998 would return 26 (because 9 + 9 + 8) is 26.
2. Write the same function above, but that takes an input from the built-in browser function, prompt().

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

Check this below code.

```
let num = 998;
function individualSum(inputNum) {
  let numStr = String(inputNum);
  let numStrArray = numStr.split("");
  let result = 0;
  let len = numStrArray.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    result = result + Number(numStrArray[i]);
  }
  console.log(result);
}
individualSum(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, with comments

```js
let n = 998;

// To string
n = String(n);

// Split
n = n.split("");

// Summ
n = n.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b), 0);

// Log
console.log(n)
```